# Problems running remote C++ program in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake, remote-access

Here is the scenario. 
I have a C++ application using CMake that has been setup on Ubuntu server machine. I have setup a remote development interface to it using Netbeans 6.9 on client machine, and I have been able to build it. 
The problem is that (as per the setup of CMake script) the executables from the program are going to another directory in the server. When I try to run the program, Netbeans asks me for executables which I can't spot out on client machine (as they are residing on server machine).
Is there a way I can get the executables on local machine OR have a way to give their location to my Netbeans application.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wondering if the "cmake" tag really belongs on this question. Seems irrelevant that the server app was built with CMake... Your question is how to run the server apps via Netbeans. I don't think it matters that the server side apps were built with CMake.